# how to remove extra padding covered with carousel controls

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My code is as shown below:

index.html

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fc2;
}


/*.container .carousel slide .carousel-inner .item active {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="../test/images/slider1.png" alt="Los Angeles" style="
                        height:100vh;width:100vw;background-color:red;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="../test/images/slider-2.png" alt="Chicago" style="
                        height:100vh;width:100vw;background-color:green;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="../test/images/slider-3.png" alt="New york" style="
                        height:100vh;width:100vw;background-color:yellow;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here , I have tried to even give margin:0,padding:0, but still there is some margin on left and right side ,so should I remove or add anything to make it work? I have even tried to remove margin from every component using * . But still it did not give me the same effect.

Comment: Sir can you please make a fiddle.

Comment: where exactly is the extra padding?

Comment: I have updated my post. In that to see that extra padding, I have used background-color of yellow for container. But somehow those images will leave little space on the left and right side and so yellow color is clearly seen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using Bootstrap, the `.container` class has `padding-left: 15px` & `padding-right: 15px` styles.

[image: container has padding]

Just set `padding: 0` to your `.container` class and it's all done.

However, be careful that in the screenshot below, you can see that **bootstrap is loaded after your css**. So if you just add `padding: 0` to your `.container` class it will be overrided by bootstrap's.

> Try changing the order of stylesheets loading in your `<head>` **so
>   yours is loaded last**.

Or just put a style attribute with `padding: 0` directly to your container `<div>`, but that's not best practice.

Result:

[image: No more padding]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your CSS, you have paddings in your `.container` class located at `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css`, precisely

```
.container{
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Just workaround those lines by overriding them if you really need to use Bootstrap.

Another solution is to use a local instance of that CSS code but customized by you, so just save the CSS file, remove those lines and use that CSS locally.